# How to execute war on local jboss server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, server, war

I have created war file of my application. How to test war file on local jboss server?

I have added it on admin console and enabled.
Using localhost:8080/ getting requested resource not found message on browser.

Comment: What context have you deployed it to. If your app is called `MyApp.war` then the path might be `localhost:8080/MyApp`

Comment: getting The requested resource is not available. msg

Comment: Check the JBoss logs to ensure the app has deployed properly. This will also give you the context root

Comment: Which jboss version are you using? The logfile would be also very important - depending on the jboss version you find it in different places. For 6/7 -> $jboss_home/standalone/log/server.log. For <6 it will be most likely in $jboss_home/server/default/log/server.log